# How do I get my toolbar to show?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have this GUI and it works perfectly however now I wanted to add a toolbar which will have a "File" button that will go down with two options, which are Exit and About. Exit is supposed to close the GUI while About should give out another JFrame box that contains a string about the assignment. For some reason, I could not get my JMenubar to show up there when I run the program. I can type stuff which lets me know if a word or a string is palindrome or not but did not have any luck with toolbar. How should I implement it so that my toolbar shows with "file" button that will have two options below? I am not so good when it comes to GUI's so I would be happy if you walk me through this.
Thanks
Here is my code below

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
public class PalindromGUI extends JFrame {

    private JTextField TextField;
    private JTextArea textArea;
    private JMenuBar menubar;
    private JMenuItem exit;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        PalindromGUI gui = new PalindromGUI();

        gui.setVisible(true);

    }

    public PalindromGUI() {

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(50,50,90,650);

//Create a panel and add components to it.
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        BorderLayout experimentLayout = new BorderLayout();

        contentPane.setLayout(experimentLayout);

        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));

        TextField = new JTextField();
        TextField.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        TextField.setOpaque(true);
        TextField.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        TextField.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        TextField.setMargin(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));//add margin 30
        TextField.setText("Enter a word to see if it is a palindrome");
        TextField.setEditable(false);

        //toolbar
        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        exit = new JMenuItem();   


        //    exit.addActionListener(new exitApp());
            contentPane.add(exit);




//         menubar.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
//        menubar.setOpaque(true);
//        menubar.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
//        menubar.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 40));
//        menubar.setMargin(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));
//        



        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
        textArea.setOpaque(true);
        textArea.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        textArea.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 40));
        textArea.setMargin(new Insets(20, 20, 20, 20));//add margin 30
        JButton enter = new JButton();
        enter.setText("GO");
        enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                String pal = textArea.getText();
                String temp = pal.replaceAll("\\W", "");

                Palindrome myPalindrome = new Palindrome(temp);

                if (myPalindrome.isPalindrome()) {
                    TextField.setText(pal + " is a palindrome");
                } else {
                    TextField.setText(pal + " is not a palindrome");
                }
                textArea.setText("");
            }
        });



        contentPane.add(enter, BorderLayout.EAST);
        contentPane.add(textArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        contentPane.add(TextField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(menubar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        setContentPane(contentPane);

//        this.add(contentPane);

        this.pack();

        this.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique is to create the JMenuBar which contains JMenu's which in turn contain JMenuItem's, e.g.:

```
//toolbar
JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");

exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");

fileMenu.add(new JMenuItem("About"));
fileMenu.add(exit);

menubar = new JMenuBar();
menubar.add(fileMenu);
setJMenuBar(menubar);
```

Comment: -1, this answer was already given 9 minutes earlier.  No need to clutter the forum with duplicate answers. Spoon feeding the code doesn't help the OP learn. Notice the follow up question. `How can I make them work?` The OP hasn't yet read the tutorial and is waiting for you to write the code.

Comment: @UniQuadrion Start by reading the tutorials provide by Camickr as well as [How to use buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to write ActionListeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html), these are basic concepts you will rescue a lot, so take the time to learn them

Comment: @camickr This isn't spoon feeding, it's just enough code to show how to build a menu. Frankly, if the answer to every question is RTFM then we might as well shut this site down.

Comment: THE answer was RTFM. The answer was to create a JMenu and add it to the menubar and then add a menuitem to the menu. The answer was given in English. You don't need to post code when a simple explanation will do. Then if more help is needed the tutorial provided a complete working program, not just a few random lines of code. The tutorial also helps the OP with the question on making a menu item work by showing how to add an ActionListener. That is the point of linking to the tutorial because it provides more information for the OP.

Comment: If it wasn't for Barry, I would still have been pondering how to do what I was trying to do. All Barry did was he got me started on the toolbar, which I accomplished the rest (adding Actionlistener and such) I mean it was a simple thing that I over-complicated. And It is not like he did the whole assignment for me. He just showed me a path of what I was trying to do. The link you sent me also helped me but took a bit more time for me to understand due to Abstractness of the material. That is why I refer places like this, to run away from abstractness of the material that can be taught easily.

Comment: `I would still have been pondering how to do what I was trying to do` - all you had to do was take 5 minutes to look at the tutorial. The tutorial states: `to set the menu bar for a JFrame, you use the setJMenuBar method. To add a JMenu to a JMenuBar, you use the add(JMenu) method. To add menu items and submenus to a JMenu, you use the add(JMenuItem) method.` Not only that, you can download, compile and test the code. There is nothing abstract about that. Did you bookmark the tutorial so you can refer to it for other questions?

Answer (score 1):

```
    menubar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menubar);
    exit = new JMenuItem();
```

You don't add anything to the menubar. You need to create a JMenu and add it to the menubar. Then you need to add your menuitem to the menu.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: -1 this doesn't actually show the OP how menus should be structured.

Comment: I am going through that link about menus. Thanks

Comment: @BarrySW19, `doesn't actually show the OP how menus should be structured` - sure it does. I used English to explain the concept. A JMenu is added to a JMenuBar and a JmenuItem is added to a JMenu. You don't need code to explain a simple structure.

Comment: @camickr Hmm, perhaps a few lines of code was the most useful way to explain after all.

Comment: @BarrySW19, of course, people are naturally lazy. I have been answering questions for a long time. I know that a basic question like this will lead to follow up questions. In my answers I try to teach people how to think and become better problem solvers by giving them the skills and resources needed to solve the problem, not only the current problem but future problems. You are not doing the OP any favours by not letting him think on his own.

Comment: Actually the way he Barry showed me  how should I go about making the toolbar gave me many ideas of doing different things in different way, which extended the horizon of my computer science skills in a way. Everyone knows how to use internet but not everyone can learn from it, which I am one of them. Sometimes you need to look at people's explanation of how they go about doing the things that you are trying to accomplish, which Barry did.  Thanks for that Barry.